# BEP20 BSC TOKEN Tax Not sent

Tags: bsc

I launched with the code below, but tax is not coming in.
Do you know the cause?

https://bscscan.com/token/0x030aa7fdd00ada3d90234a6dcba050d217b161c0?a=0x030aa7fdd00ada3d90234a6dcba050d217b161c0#code

Comment: What do you mean by "tax is not coming in"? What were you expecting? What did it happen?

Answer (score 0):

It does take a fee in LETI tokens:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x030aa7fdd00ada3d90234a6dcba050d217b161c0#tokentxns